# The log is not detecting the failure (locally)after upgrading to serenityCoreVersion = '4.0.1'

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, bdd, serenity-bdd

When I upgraded to the latest version (4.0.1) of Serenity, I am not able to see the step-by-step console log locally when a step actually fails (I intentionally used the wrong element locator in one step to make it fail). The log is not detecting the failure, and it shows that all steps passed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgm7S.png)